# Rails: Nested Models Not Saving Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have two models, Trips and Locations.  A trip has a origin and a destination which are both references to Location:

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :destination, :origin, :start_datetime, :transportation, :trip_type, :destination_attributes, :origin_attributes

  enum_attr :trip_type, %w(Hitchhiker Driver)

  has_one :origin, :class_name => 'Location' , :primary_key => :origin, :foreign_key => :id
  has_one :destination, :class_name => 'Location' , :primary_key => :destination, :foreign_key => :id

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :origin, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :destination, :allow_destroy => true

  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :name, :destination, :origin, :start_datetime, :transportation, :trip_type

end


class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :latitude, :longitude

  geocoded_by :address

  before_validation :geocode

  validates_presence_of :address
  validate :geocoding_was_found

  def geocoding_was_found
    errors.add(:address, 'is not valid') if latitude.nil? || longitude.nil?
  end

end
```

When calling create in the controller, it saves all of the records (two location records and the trips record) but does not save the association.

```
def create

    @trip = Trip.new(params[:trip])
    @trip.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @trip.save
        format.html { redirect_to @trip, notice: 'Trip was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @trip, status: :created, location: @trip }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @trip.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I am using nested forms so the data for location is being passed in through origin_attributes and destination_attributes.  My guess is it is because the two fields are called origin and destination instead of _id.

Comment: With the has_one relation, each location can only belong to one trip. Also, location should have trip_id in attr_accessible

Comment: Ok but I want to have an origin and a destination for a trip.  Does origin and destination need to a has_many relationship?

Comment: I think you need to get ride of the primary and foreign key stuff. You do not need to change these to a `has_many` relationship, for sure. Trip needs a `origin_id` and a 'destination_id`, and this should work fine. I would try it and offer a real answer, but someone else can. I think that's the ticket though.